# Filter nested serializer django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, models

I have this model serializer:

```
class QuoteTemplateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)
    quote = QuoteSerializer()
    language_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = QuoteTemplate
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'quote', 'language_list')
```

And this views:

```
class QuoteViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = q.Quote
    serializer_class = serializers.QuoteSerializer
    permission_classes = [
         GallantViewSetPermissions
     ]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(client__isnull=False)



class QuoteTemplateViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    model = q.QuoteTemplate
    serializer_class = serializers.QuoteTemplateSerializer
    permission_classes = [
         GallantViewSetPermissions
     ]

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects
```

I want to list Quote Model and QuoteTemplate model. However, when listing Quote model I want to skip those records that don't have a client and when listing QuoteTemplate model I don't want to filter.

How can I achieve this with my current views? Right now my lists are getting filtered on both cases.

**Edit:**

I've already tried using serializers.SerializerMethodField() however I get errors on my create() and update() functions when trying to pop information out of `validated_data`.

Comment: The code is correct, its unclear what `all_for(self.request.user)` does maybe its the cause of that behavior.

Comment: I just want the filter to be ignored when used as nested.

Comment: Maybe it would explain better if you provided the Models. You only provide ModelSerializer and two ViewSet

Answer (score 0):

You should check what your viewsets are returning. Are you certain `q.Quote.objects.all_for(self.request.user).filter(client__isnull=False)` and `q.QuoteTemplate.objects.all_for(self.request.user)` are returning the correct querysets? There is no logic in your serializer, it just serializes the values in the queryset.

Comment: Thanks for your response djq, the response is fine the only thing i need is Quote to be filtered by client when called through QuoteViewSet and not filtered by client when called through QuoteTemplateViewSet.

Comment: I don't think your response is fine. Based on this comment, your `QuoteTemplateViewSet` should return a quryset `self.model.objects.all()` and not filter using the user

Comment: My development is Sass so each user has its own quotes that's why the all_for().